# Solving a VRP using OR-Tools with a quadratic tardiness cost

Tags: c++, or-tools

I'm looking to solve a vehicle routing problem with soft time windows using or-tools in c++.
However, in my use case the tardiness cost should be quadratic, so that if a vehicle is x time units late, then the cost is x^2.
It therefore seems that I am unable to use `SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound`, as it incurs a linear cost.

Is there a good way to do this?

I've looked at `SetCumulVarPiecewiseLinearCost` but it seems to require me to create an array of datapoints per time unit and per time variable. Since I have around 1000 nodes in my graph and the time domains are quite large, this approach seems rather costly. I was hoping that maybe there was some way of doing this with a lambda instead of an explicit piecewise linear function.